# Summation by elements of vectors in R

Tags: r, sum

I'm looking for a much nicer way to sum vectors by elements.
Suppose we have 3 vectors:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
b <- c(5, 6, 7, 8)
c <- c(9, 10, 11, 12)
```

I want

```
d = c(15, 18, 21, 24)
```

The way I've been working at it is through a for-loop, but I think that's a bit tedious, and can be slow with large vectors, ie:

```
for (j in 1:4){
   d[j] = sum(c(a[j], b[j], c[j]))
}
```

Is there a function in R that would just add these vectors together by element position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `colSums` after we `rbind` the vectors 'a', 'b', and 'c'

```
 colSums(rbind(a,b,c))
 #[1] 15 18 21 24
```

Or we can place it in a `list` and use `Reduce/+`

```
Reduce(`+`, list(a,b,c))
#[1] 15 18 21 24
```

I used `colSums` as `+` have some limitations when there are `NA` elements.  For example.

```
 a1 <- c(3, 2, NA, 1)
 b1 <- c(5, NA, 3, 2)
 a1+b1
 #[1]  8 NA NA  3
```

whereas `na.rm` argument in `colSums` can be useful for such conditions.

```
 colSums(rbind(a1,b1), na.rm=TRUE)
 #[1] 8 2 3 3
```

Even the `Reduce` approach is not good.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
a+b+c
```

vectorized math! cheers

Answer (score 2):

@nongkrong is correct, `a+b+c` is the easiest way to do this.

@akrun also has valid points about NA's.

But I would like to point out **1)** other functions that work similarly, **2)** functions that are vectorized versions of their more common counterparts, and **3)** the function that will help you perform this task in any situation.

1. The same idiom works for `a*b*c`

   ```
   a*b*c
   [1]  45 120 231 384
   ```
2. For `min` or `max`, there's a different function to use: `pmin` and
   `pmax`, respectively.

   ```
   pmin(a,b,c)
   [1] 1 2 3 4
   ```
3. If you want to apply a function element-wise to a series of vectors,
   try `mapply`.

   ```
   mapply(sum, a, b, c) # this answers your question!
   [1] 15 18 21 24
   ```

   *Note, in when using `+` in conjunction with `mapply` (i.e., `mapply("+", a, b)`) you can only use 2 vectors b/c `+` expects 2 values (whereas `a+b+c` handles 3 values at once but calls `+` twice!).*

Also note that `pmin` and `sum` (within `mapply`) can handle NA's easily through the `na.rm=TRUE` arugment (e.g., `mapply(sum, a, b, c, na.rm=TRUE)`)

Good luck, and welcome to vectorization and other nifty tricks in R :)